# Update query MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to update my table using the following query...

```
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `outgoings` (id, user_id, bill, bill_name, bill_description, bill_colour ) VALUES ('$id', '$uid', '$bill', '$billname', '$billdescription', '$billcolour') WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

It returns...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id, user_id, bill, bill_name, bill_description, bill_colour ) VALUES ('', '8464' at line 1
```

Ive tried removing ' around my variables and googling for alternative methods but cant seem to figutre out what imdoing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this syntax for `update` statements:

```
UPDATE `outgoings` set id = '$id', user_id = '$uid' ... where ...
```

You got it mixed with `insert` statement I guess.

Comment: This is correct. The syntax the OP used is for INSERT and doesn't work for UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ID is empty (`...VALUES ('',...`). Should there be an ID there?

Answer (score 0):

Your $id seems to be empty or not defined yet. Read mysql.error() up to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The update query has different syntax, something like that:

```
UPDATE `outgoings` SET user_id='$uid', bill='$bill' WHERE id = '$id'
```